# Protractor + jasmine : run same spec twice with different params:

Tags: jasmine

Hi this is my config :

exports.config = {

```
    allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
    specs: [
        './e2e/xyz/xyz.e2e-spec.ts',
    ],
    multiCapabilities: [
        {
            browserName: 'chrome',
            chromeOptions: {
                args: ['--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--window-size=1024x768', '--no-sandbox']
            }
        }
        /* Failing in Jeniks, TODO : need to fix this,
        {
            browserName: 'firefox',
            firefoxOptions: {
                args: ['--headless']
            },
            'moz:firefoxOptions': {
                args: ['--headless']
            }
        }
        */
    ],
    directConnect: true,
    chromeOnly: false,
    baseUrl: nconf.get('BASE_URL'),
    framework: 'jasmine',
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 120000,
        includeStackTrace : true,
        print: function () { }
    },
    restartBrowserBetweenTests: false,
    useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
    onPrepare: function () {
        require('ts-node').register({
            project: './e2e/tsconfig.json'
        });
        let SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter').SpecReporter;
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({displayStacktrace: 'spec'}));
    },
    params: {
        login: {
            username: nconf.get('USERNAME'),
            password: nconf.get('PASSWORD'),
            username_d: nconf.get('D_USERNAME'),
            password_d: nconf.get('D_PASSWORD')
            
        },
        sddc_id: nconf.get('SDDC_ID'),
        org_id: nconf.get('ORG_ID'),
        env: nconf.get('env'),
        d_sddc_id: nconf.get('D_SDDC_ID')
    }
```

Now I want to call xyz.e2e-spec.ts twice for different usernames and passwords. Is there a way to run "describe('SOme work', () => {).  twice in xyz.e2e-spec.ts?. I mean for loop wont works on this since describe is a function.

Comment: I think this should help you: https://blog.harveydelaney.com/running-multiple-test-cases-in-jasmine/

Comment: Hey I tried this before but my describe functions looks like :
describe('Some Page', () => {   
        beforeAll(() => {
loginUtil(username ,password);}

 afterAll(() => {
            Util.reloadBrowser();
        });
it('verify title!', () => {
            Util.logInfo("verify title exists');
            expect(Locators.Button()).toBeTruthy();
        });

}


And while or for loop for this takes forever and it gives this error "compacts near heap limit allocation failed – javascript heap out of memory"

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure then.